# Creating a View in BigQuery from Temporary Function and Dynamic SQL

Tags: google-bigquery

I want to create a view dynamically with a string generated by a temporary function. The code below fails with `Creating views with temporary user-defined functions is not supported`. How can I create the view without permanently registering the function?

```sql
CREATE TEMP FUNCTION CreateViewString()
  RETURNS STRING
  AS (("select 1 as col"));

EXECUTE IMMEDIATE "CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW `project.dataset.view` AS " || CreateViewString()
```

Answer (score 1):

As a workaround one can store the result of the function and then drop the function.

```sql
DECLARE viewString STRING;

CREATE TEMP FUNCTION CreateViewString()
  RETURNS STRING
  AS (("select 1 as col"));

SET viewString = CreateViewString();

DROP FUNCTION CreateViewString;

EXECUTE IMMEDIATE "CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW `project.dataset.view` AS " || viewString
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm posting this answer for posterity. This is a [known issue](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/208450770#comment5) that the BigQuery team is aware of and improvements have been under consideration. You can also **`STAR`** the issue to receive automatic updates and give it traction by referring to this [link](https://developers.google.com/issue-tracker/guides/subscribe#starring_an_issue). Suggested workarounds are as follows.

1. Drop the UDF before view creation, this will prevent the script from attaching the UDF in the last statement. (mentioned in the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72181779/15745884) by @p13rr0m)
2. If the view is not related to the UDF or temporary table execution, run them as separate queries.